# Is it halal to work at this job?

Tags: halal-haram, money, finance

Assalam alikoum

My question is related to a job I was working on through the internet before, where I was earning money thats in crypto payment method, so basically I was in the niche of NFTs, I dont really know if you know what NFTs mean but if you search it, you will find some information about it.
I was working for marketing agencies where they provide marketing services for NFT projects, and I would bring clients to these agencies to earn a commission. Now, these NFT projects, some have artworks, some have 3D designs, etc, and when I researched, I saw that if NFTs have artworks or designs of humans, then they are haram. My question is: Is the money I earned through getting clients halal or haram even though I wasn't directly selling artworks or spirits or anything, and can I still do this kind of job in the future?

I'm sorry for the long question, but I need a detailed answer on this.

And jazakum allah khayran

Comment: I don't know much about Islam, but if what you were describing would be haram, selling paper would also be haram as it could be misused for sinful drawings.

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, **the permissibility of earnings is often tied to nature of work and the source of income.** While dealing with NFTs, particularly those involving artworks or designs of humans, can raise concerns due to prohibition of images of living beings in Islamic art, your role as a marketer promoting such projects may NOT inherently make your earnings Haram.

Since you are not directly involved in creating or selling the prohibited content, but rather facilitating marketing services, the income generated through client referrals may be considered Halal. However, it is advisable to **exercise caution and ensure that the products or services you promote comply with Islamic principles.**

It is recommended to prioritize projects that align with Islamic values and **avoid promoting NFTs that contain impermissible elements**.

Comment: I appreciate your response, may Allah bless you and your family, does that mean I don't have to worry about my income?